# How to place a value outside stacked bar chart in xlsxwriter

Tags: python, label, bar-chart, xlsxwriter

in a stacked bar chart, is there's a way to put the value outside the chart using `xlsxwriter`?
[image: stacked bar chart]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add data labels to chart series in XlsxWriter charts.

See the [Chart series option: Data Labels](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.org/working_with_charts.html#chart-series-option-data-labels) section of the [Working with Charts](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.org/working_with_charts.html#chart-series-option-data-labels) part of the docs.

However, I'm not sure if Excel has an option to put data labels outside the bar for stacked bar charts.